# access array of c structures in python

Tags: python, struct, ctypes

I am unable to access the array properly beyond the 0th element. How can I access the non-zero elements? If I try to access the non-zero elements, Python shell is restarting. Code below

```c
struct s_xl_can_msg {  
         unsigned long     id;
         unsigned short    flags;
         unsigned short    dlc;
         XLuint64          res1;
         unsigned char     data [MAX_MSG_LEN];
         XLuint64          res2;
       };

// BASIC bus message structure
union s_xl_tag_data {
        struct s_xl_can_msg                    msg;
        struct s_xl_chip_state                 chipState;
        union  s_xl_lin_msg_api                linMsgApi;    
        struct s_xl_sync_pulse                 syncPulse;
        struct s_xl_daio_data                  daioData; 
        struct s_xl_transceiver                transceiver; 
      };

struct s_xl_event {
         XLeventTag           tag;             // 1                          
         unsigned char        chanIndex;       // 1
         unsigned short       transId;         // 2
         unsigned short       portHandle;      // 2 internal use only !!!!
         unsigned short       reserved;        // 2
         XLuint64             timeStamp;       // 8
         union s_xl_tag_data  tagData;         // 32 Bytes 
       };
typedef  struct s_xl_event  XLevent;

xlReceive (portHandle, *pEventCount, XLevent *pEventList)
```

Python code below:

```python
XLeventtag = ctypes.c_ubyte
XLuint64 = ctypes.c_ulonglong

class s_xl_can_msg(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("id", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("flags", ctypes.c_ushort),
                ("dlc", ctypes.c_ushort),
                ("res1", XLuint64),
                ("data", ctypes.c_ubyte*MAX_MSG_LEN)]

class s_xl_tag_data(ctypes.Union):
    _fields_ = [("msg", s_xl_can_msg),
                ("chipState", s_xl_chip_state),
                ("linMsgApi", s_xl_lin_msg_api),
                ("syncPulse", s_xl_sync_pulse),
                ("daioData", s_xl_daio_data),
                ("transceiver", s_xl_transceiver)]

class s_xl_event(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ =[ ("tag", XLeventtag),
                ("chanIndex", ctypes.c_ubyte),
                ("transId", ctypes.c_ushort),
                ("portHandle", ctypes.c_ushort),
                ("reserved", ctypes.c_ushort),
                ("timeStamp", XLuint64),
                ("tagData", s_xl_tag_data)]

event_list = canlib.XLevent(100)
print event_list
event_count = ctypes.c_uint(100)
print event_count
ok = can.receive(phandle, event_count, event_list)
```

I was not able to access the `event_list` properly beyond the 0th element. How can I access the non-zero elements of `event_list`?

Comment: How does `canlib` relate to `can`? What's `canlib.XLevent`? Is this another name for the `s_xl_event` class? If so, do you want to create an array of 100 events? Is `can.receive` supposed to be `xlReceive`? Can you fix the prototype for that? You've got `*pEventCount` there with no type, but either way it looks like you should be passing `ctypes.byref(event_count)`, though it's not clear why that's to be passed by reference. Does it get updated with the actual event count that was copied to the buffer?

Comment: @eryksun, XLevent is another name for s_xl_event and I want to create an array of 100 events to receive 100 messages. can.receive refers to xlReceive.event_count will return how many messages were received and copied to buffer. All this functions are part of a c dll which I am trying to use in Python

Comment: `XLevent(100)` creates a single instance with `tag == 100`. To instead create an array use `event_list = (XLevent * 100)()`. Then call `ok = receive(phandle, ctypes.byref(event_count), event_list)`.

Comment: @eryksun: thanks (XLevent *100) created an array. how can I initialize this array with zero

Comment: `(XLevent *100)` creates an array type. You have to call it to create an instance, as I showed. The array instance has a buffer that's `sizeof(XLevent) * 100` bytes, which are initialized to zero.